# Why does Array.of exist?

Tags: javascript

Why does `Array.of` exist? AFAIK it simply creates an array from the arguments passed (i.e `Array.of(1,2,3)` -> `[1,2,3]`).

This [JSPerf](https://jsperf.app/gelobi) shows that this simple replacement function (which works exactly the same way) performs 80-90% faster than `Array.of`

```js
const array_of = (...args) => [...args];
```

^ this is valid ES6 and so is Array.of

Comment: There are iterable things that are not arrays, and `Array.of()` lets you convert them.

Comment: Well, [`Array.of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of) does more, including calling the constructor function it's supplied (usually, but not always `Array`), setting `this`, and so forth.

Comment: @Pointy the spread operator does the same

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev yes that's true, I was thinking about that after typing in the comment. The only thing I can think of is that `Array.of()` is an actual function and not a syntax element, so it could in principal be passed as a callback etc.

Comment: Oh also the `.of()` method is inheritable, so subclasses can be the `this` value and you get a subclass instance out of the call, which I did not know until just now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's totally OK. Passing a lot of parameters to a function and creating its stack frame is just an expensive operation.

Also if you refer to the documentation, it's a static method of `Array`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of

So there're additional scenarios how to use it, like subclassing `Array` so you can create instances of your subclass of `Array`. That could be useful, like passing it by reference as a factory for your subclass.

While its less performant that could be not important on usual data sizes used in web app.

Answer (score 2):

I can also say that it is because of `Array.of` can be used in older browsers that do not support the spread operator. It is the part of **ECMAScript 6 (ES6)** as built-in object. It is more consistent with other built-in methods, such as `Array.from` and `Array.map`.

> The main reason for, it is to provide more **predictable constructor** than the traditional Array constructor.

This above means that when you create `Array(3)` it creates an empty array length 3, not an array with single element, 3. In case of `Array.of` It always creates an array with the arguments you pass to it. which is good to not making unexpected results.

Comment: AFAIK The spread operator (...) works on any iterables and was introduced in ES6 with Array.of.

Answer (score 1):

Fair question. I will try to give it a fair answer

My argument is that

```
const arr = Array.of(...args);
```

Is more clear than

```
const arr = (...args) => [...args];
```

**Why?**

In both cases we are creating a new array. This is crucial because arrays are handled by reference. Long story short: we all agree that the below code will update both arrays

```
const x = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
const y = x;

y.push(4);

console.log(x, y);
```

Both *x* and *y* arrays has now 4 elements, because *y* is only a reference to the already created *x* array. Any modification in *y* will address the instance referenced by both *x* and *y*

That is why, when we are cloning complex types (not primitives) we intend the new instance to be separated and *not* affect the original value. In our example, will will make the following modification to get more excepted results

```
const x = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
const y = Array.of(...x);

y.push(4);

console.log(x, y);
```

It is clear that *y* is a clone of *x*, for me at least, way more than just

```
const x = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
const y = (...args) => [...args]; // smae effect, still - are we sure we understand what's going on?

y.push(4);

console.log(x, y);
```

**My question is:** why stopping here? What if we need to clone an object instead?

While some argue that this is a cool way to do it

```
const x = { hello: 'world' };

const y = { ...food };
```

I think that the classic way is more readable

```
const x = { hello: 'world' };

const y = Object.assign({}, x);
```

You don't have to be javascript master in order to understand it

Also, it worth mentioning that for both cases you can make a clone by using

```
const x = { something: 'else', with: [ { 'way': 'more' }, levels: [ 1, 2, 3 ] ] };

const y = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
```

Which is a very simple way (or a dirty hack) to serialize and desterilize an object, creating a perfect clone of it

### In conclusion:

When performance matters, the performance of the team is crucial as well. Most chances that they will understand and also appreciate more performant code (and will probably be bitter whenever they encounter `forEach` loop)

In any other case, keep it simple for other humans to maintain your code base

Cheers